# local wordpress blog issues

Tags: localhost, local-installation

i have recently started a local blog, installed wordpress 3.5 correctly, even posted on it, when i view it on my machine using the IP or localhost, i see the entire pages correctly, but when i view it on any other machine, the view is plain HTML, no CSS, no JS, just plain old HTML

i have tried setting up the permissions, also i am using xubuntu 12.04 and have installed LAMP stack properly, there are no issues with it, as it is obvious because the site works properly on my localhost

Answer (score 1):

You've set the "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" at `wp-admin -> Settings -> General` to `localhost`. `localhost` means "this computer". That setting will work if you view the site on the same machine that the server runs on. If you view the site on any other machine the browser will look for files on "this computer"-- the computer the *browser* is on-- and of course won't find them.

You need to give your server a local static address-- usually something like `192.168.1.10`-- and use that instead of `localhost` in the settings. That will work for any computer on your local network.