# Show wordpress locally in xammp and in iPhone via ip

Tags: apache, configuration

My wordpress site works fine on my mac via localhost, using Xammp. I want to view the site on my iPhone. So I type in 192.168.0.2 and voila, it brings up my localhost directory. I then click on the site in question and the content is there but no styling or images. I realise that this is because the paths to all the resources is hardcoded into the wordpress database. So when I am accessing the url via 192.168.0.2/mywebsitename on my iPhone, it's looking for all the resources using a base url of localhost/mywebsitename. Localhost path doesn't exist on my iPhone, only 192.168.0.2 does.

So has anyone found a solution to this little issue? How can I see a wordpress installation by ip address and by localhost access?

Comment: None of your paths should be hardcoded. Make use of functions like `get_home_url()` or `bloginfo('home')` among many many others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [local wordpress blog issues](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106977/local-wordpress-blog-issues)

Comment: @Waldermort, the paths are hardcoded by default in Wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the site url which is stored in the database based on what domain you are viewing the site from. Add the following to `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/yourwebsitename' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME );
```

If you use a subdirectory install (ie: you view the site from `http://192.168.0.2/yourwebstename` but the WordPress core files are stored in `http://192.168.0.2/yourwebstename/wp` (or similar), you will need to add this to the second line:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME . '/wp' );
```

Comment: that works great.  What exactly is it doing though?

Comment: @Nicola It uses values from the server to tell it what domain is being served, and uses that domain to override the `site_url` and `home` options in the database.

Comment: ahh I see.  So does wordpress use a constant when getting resources via url, rather than looking in the database for the path?  So it does it once and stores it in a constant?

Comment: No, by default it uses the value in the database which can be changed under the *Settings > General* admin menu. However, if you define the constant it uses that instead of the database value

Answer (score 0):

Yes you won't get style and images until you tell your iPhone to look for an IP instead of localhost.

Your iPhone is searching in

`http://localhost/...`

Actually iPhone is searching on its own localhost, not your mac.

First try enter a url manually for an image.

```
http://192.168.0.2/sub-folder-of-wordpress-if-exists/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/image.png
```

and check if it shows your image.

To make it work permanently, find and replace url string from your database **localhost** to  **192.168.0.2**

Recommend use [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin

Comment: "To make it work permanently, find and replace url string from your database localhost to 192.168.0.2" That's changing one problem to another. What happens if he gets a new router with a different IP address?

Comment: I don't want it to work on one and not the other, I want to view the site on my mac and my iPhone.

Comment: It will work on both buy on mac you also need to access it through your IP