# Use stylesheet from a different location

Tags: css

I haven't done wordpress development in quite some time so it looks like some things have changed (naturally). I'm using codekit to compile my themes sass files and minify my scripts as well. It requires that all files have a specific output path, in other words I can't specify that the style.scss file should compile to a style.css file in the root directory. It has to go into a folder of some sort relative to the root folder, like a /css folder.

So in googling around trying to see if there was a way to tell wordpress to look into the /css folder and look for a file called site.css I found this code I can add to my functions.php file...

```
add_filter('stylesheet_uri','wpi_stylesheet_uri',10,2);

/**
 * wpi_stylesheet_uri
 * overwrite default theme stylesheet uri
 * filter stylesheet_uri
 * @see get_stylesheet_uri()
 */
function wpi_stylesheet_uri($stylesheet_uri, $stylesheet_dir_uri){

    return $stylesheet_dir_uri.'/css/site.css';
}
```

Now if I'm not mistaken it looks like I have to call that function? But when I try to call it, say in my header.php I get an error.

To summarize I am looking for the preferred way to change where wordpress looks for my themes stylesheet.

Comment: "*To summarize I am looking for the preferred way to change where wordpress looks for my themes stylesheet.*" - this is a **very localized** concern. WordPress uses the main stylesheet for its own purposes. The Theme doesn't ever have to enqueue it at all. So, there's no real need to change where WordPress looks for it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a theme's `style.css` as normal but [just include the header information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet). This will be a config file only.

The [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) your stylesheet(s). You can use any path you'd like. I think this is what you need:

```
function register_theme_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'theme-styles', site_url( '/css/site.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-styles' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_theme_styles' );
```

Comment: Getting somewhere, now I'm getting the in error console that it's not found, but it's clearly there, it's looking for the file here...

localhost:8888/project-name/css/site.css

Is that correct or should it be looking to the whole relative path?

Comment: You will need a complete URL, yes, and using `localhost` is only going to work if you access the site from the same machine as serves it. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106977/local-wordpress-blog-issues/106993#106993

Comment: You may also have permission issues on that directory/file.

Comment: Hmm I've never had these problems before with this setup. I'm using MAMP, is there some sort of apache or php setting that needs to be turned on or off to get localhost to work correctly?

Comment: Any reason you're using `site_url()`, instead of the far more useful (and far safer) `get_template_directory_uri()`? By using `site_url()`, you need to include the path to the Theme itself, which is by default (but not always) `/wp-content/themes/{theme-slug}`, so your answer doesn't actually pass the correct path. `site_url( '/css/style.css' )` would return `example.com/{wordpress-install-directory}/css/style.css`, which is *not* the Theme's stylesheet path.

Comment: @ChipBennett : My understanding of the question is that the OP needs to load styles from the root directory of the site-- "... compile to a style.css file in the root directory. It has to go into a folder of some sort relative to the root folder, like a /css folder"

Comment: If that's true, then this is an insanely localized question.

Comment: The technique for solving the problem is very general though.

Comment: I want wordpress to look for the theme stylesheet inside of /css/site.css and not for style.css in the themes root

Comment: @Jordan : that is what this code does except that I named the stylesheet `style.css`. You can apply the code to any filename or directory you want with a trivial edit.

Comment: Here is what I did
`function register_theme_styles() {
     wp_register_style( 'theme-styles', get_template_directory_uri('/css/site.css'));
     wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-styles' );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_theme_styles' );`
And in the console it's trying to go here...
`http://localhost:8888/karmen-noel/wp-content/themes/karmen-noel/?ver=3.8.1`

Comment: Your file is actually here, correct: `http://localhost:8888/karmen-noel/css/site.css`?

Comment: You can't pass a parameter to [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri). It doesn't accept parameters. Do this instead: `get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/site.css'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter, to filter out styles with any condition, or change output href string, example:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```